# Javascript `MediaRecorder` audio stream isn't working in Safari v16.6

Tags: javascript, safari, mediarecorder

I am trying to record a voice stream via the Safari browser, but the code I have written doesn't play the recorded voice. I will attach the sample code below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Audio Recording Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Audio Recording Example</h1>
<button id="startButton">Start Recording</button>
<button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
<audio id="audioPlayer" controls></audio>

<script>
    const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
    const stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
    const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
    let mediaRecorder;
    let audioChunks = [];

    async function startRecording() {
        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                if (event.data.size > 0) {
                    audioChunks.push(event.data);
                }
            };

            mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                audioPlayer.src = audioUrl;
            };

            mediaRecorder.start();
            startButton.disabled = true;
            stopButton.disabled = false;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    }

    startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        startRecording();
    });

    stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === 'recording') {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            startButton.disabled = false;
            stopButton.disabled = true;
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is read/record audio from safari browser and save that clip as a audio format (later pass it to the API service to do some processing).